# how to make JFXPanel to get focus if clicked anywhere on it not on children

Tags: javafx, focus, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have JFXPanel with a textbox and few buttons on it. I want to lost focus of textbox if user click on anywhere other than child controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my working example:

override the mouse click event of JFXPanel as follows:

```
          jfxPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {                    
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    if(!toolbarJFX.getScene().getFocusOwner().isPressed()) {
                        toolbarJFX.getScene().getRoot().requestFocus();
                    }
                }

            });
```